# What does the "build" keyword do?

Tags: bash, shell, bazel

in a bash file, There is code like below. searched for shell commands and found no build-related stuff.What is the role of this **build** in the bash file? This bash file is used to install **bazel**

```
build --curses=no
build --curses=no
build --show_task_finish
```

Comment: It's a command of some type. It's not *part of* `bash` in anyway.

Comment: Is this a `.bazelrc` file?

Comment: No,this is a .bash  file

Comment: Did you look at `bazel` documentation like `https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html` (with `build` and option `show_task_finish`) ?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I understand.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`build` could be an alias, function script or binary in your path.  This has not nothing to do with bazel.  You can execute `type build` in your shell prompt to see what `build` refers to.